# Node.js - Can't bind a udp6 socket to a specific address

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, network-interface, stun

From Node, this list of addresses available:

```
var os = require('os');
os.networkInterfaces()
```

prints:

```
{ lo0:
   [ { address: '::1',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
       scopeid: 0,
       internal: true },
     { address: '127.0.0.1',
       netmask: '255.0.0.0',
       family: 'IPv4',
       mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
       internal: true },
     { address: 'fe80::1',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
       scopeid: 1,
       internal: true } ],
  en0:
   [ { address: 'fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe1f:3939',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '28:cf:e9:1f:39:39',
       scopeid: 4,
       internal: false },
     { address: '10.0.0.8',
       netmask: '255.255.255.0',
       family: 'IPv4',
       mac: '28:cf:e9:1f:39:39',
       internal: false } ],
  awdl0:
   [ { address: 'fe80::e46a:6cff:fe68:a76a',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: 'e6:6a:6c:68:a7:6a',
       scopeid: 8,
       internal: false } ] }
```

But if I try to create specific udp sockets, I can bind udp4 but not udp6 sockets.

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var udp4 = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
udp4.bind(null, '10.0.0.8');
udp4.address()
```

prints

```
{ address: '10.0.0.8', family: 'IPv4', port: 65061 }
```

but

```
var udp6 = dgram.createSocket('udp6');
udp6.bind(null, 'fe80::e46a:6cff:fe68:a76a');
```

throws:

```
Error: bind EADDRNOTAVAIL fe80::e46a:6cff:fe68:a76a
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at dgram.js:213:18
    at doNTCallback3 (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:399:17)
```

The same thing happens with the address 'fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe1f:3939'. Note, I'm running these statements one by one in Nodes' REPL, so bind has completed by the time I try to check the address.

I can do

```
udp6.bind()
udp6.address()
```

which prints

```
{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 51897 }
```

but that doesn't tell me which address it's bound to (which I NEED in order to inform other peers).

Why can I bind to a specific IPv4 address but not an IPv6 address?  This seems inconsistent.  Is this possibly a bug in the runtime? [Relevant bug in Node issue tracker.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4274)

I need to have udp sockets that have specific addresses that reflect what's available from os.networkInterfaces as I'm [building](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-rtc-peer-connection) an [ICE agent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245).

I'm using Node v4.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like I needed a background in [Link-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

The gist is that with IPv4, you usually use a protocol like DHCP to get assigned a local IP address.  If you don't, you can pick one and hope you don't collide with other hosts on the network.  Such an address is called a "Link Local Address."  These were optional in IPv4, and are now required in IPv6.  The Link Local Address always has the prefix fe80:: prefix for IPv6 addresses.

In Node.js, you CAN listen on the link local address, but you MUST suffix the address string with the interface name, ex:

```
udp6.bind(null, 'fe80::e46a:6cff:fe68:a76a%en0');
```

That string in particular can be found from running ifconfig.

Then, other peers can contact you IF they are on the same network, but they too must specify the interface of the network device on the same network. ex.

```
nc6 -u fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe1f:3939%wlp3s0 65022
```

Where wlp3s0 was the interface of a friend's wireless NIC.

If they plugged in ethernet and wound up on the same network, they could then send through their ethernet interface, but not unless it was connected to the same local network.

Also, the IP addresses I posted showed that my home router was not assigning an IPv6 address.  At work, I was getting an IPv6 address, so I could listen on a non-fe80-prefixed address no problem.  At work, os.networkInterfaces() looked more like:

```
  en0:
   [ { address: 'fe80::2acf:e9ff:fe1f:3939',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '28:cf:e9:1f:39:39',
       scopeid: 4,
       internal: false },
     { address: '10.252.28.131',
       netmask: '255.255.248.0',
       family: 'IPv4',
       mac: '28:cf:e9:1f:39:39',
       internal: false },
     { address: '2620:101:80fc:224:2acf:e9ff:fe1f:3939',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '28:cf:e9:1f:39:39',
       scopeid: 0,
       internal: false },
     { address: '2620:101:80fc:224:4d78:1087:39a2:65d7',
       netmask: 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::',
       family: 'IPv6',
       mac: '28:cf:e9:1f:39:39',
       scopeid: 0,
       internal: false } ],
```

So I could successfully bind to any 2620: prefixed address.

Finally, for my ICE agent, the [updated draft spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ice-rfc5245bis-00#section-4.1.1.1) says "host candidates corresponding to IPv6 link-local addresses MUST NOT be gathered."

Comment: Does this also apply to private IPv6 addresses? That is: fd00 and fc00 prefixes?